# Ansible - how to retrieve value from dict passing in the list in extra vars

Tags: dictionary, ansible

So this is my dilemma... I am requiring a user to enter the name of a database (i.e. dbx) and the location (canada or america) through extra-vars (-e "dc=canada" -e "dbname=dbx".  From that, I am going read the vars

```
  vars:
    dbx:
      canada:
        dbu: db1
        home: /u01/app/oracle
      america:
        dbu: db2
        home: /u01/app/oracle
```

to get the dbu.  The dbu will then be compared to databases running on the host

```
- name: see if db is running on this host
  command: echo database is running here
  when: dbu == item.database_name
  with_items: 
    - "{{custom python module}}"
```

I can get the value if I put

```
- name: output
  register: x
  debug:
    msg: "{{ dbx[dc].dbu }}"
```

However if I change dbx to the value of dbname, it errors out.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to use a [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) => `- debug: msg="{{ lookup('vars', dbname)[dc].dbu }}"`

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, that works on Ansible 2.5+ but what about 2.3? (need it work on Linux 5 servers )

Comment: You could also just nest your variable one layer deeper - keep all the `dbname` structures under a variable called `db_configs` or similar

Comment: Hi lxop, if I were to nest it one layer deeper how would I be able to retrieve it (ansible 2.3)

Comment: => `yourtopnestedvar[dbname][dc].dbu`. Meanwhile you should consider using an up-to-date version of ansible, especially when doing so is as easy as `pip install --upgrade ansible`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zeitounator and lxop.

By adding another nested loop info:

I was able to get the result by your suggestion:

```
{{ info[g_db][dc].dbu }}
```